# Does PvZ 2 Piñata Parties only appear when all worlds are unlocked?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I haven't obtained any piñata parties in few days. Does it require all worlds unlocked before a piñata party unlocks?

Comment: even if it isn't a duplicate, rolling back grammatical fixes and calling people dumbasses isn't going to get you the attention you want.

Comment: Rolled back to something readable.

Answer (score 1):

Piñata parties events occur whether or not you finished the game.